# Bootstrap token-input won't accept typing in on text on modal dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tokenize, bootstrap-tokenfield

I have a popup dialog which i have added a div tokenized later by bootstrap js.

I am facing one major problem though. When i make the dialog modal, for some reason i can't fgure out why and where am losing typed in text though keydown and keyup events are registered successfully. Basically you can't type and see what you typed on the .token-input.

The same functionally works perfectly fine when i make the dialog non modal, but then i need this dialog modal.

Could someone have experienced such a problem in the past?

I will be glad for any possible pointers.

Thanks!

Comment: Give us some code to work with. What have you tried?

Comment: can you post a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: It way too much js code but let me try and cut it down to the relevant pieces shortly. Thanks

Comment: I have tried to keep things short for easy scanning through. Here is a fiddle with the code where the tokenizing is done.
http://jsfiddle.net/ivanoronee/9rxp2/1/